# Rails 4.2.7.1 doesn't include all image-subdirectories of asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

After a upgrade from rails 4.1.9 to rails 4.2.7.1 the asset pipeline (pre-compile) doesn't work properly.

My structure:

```
- app/assets/images/platform/panel
   - /comics    -> [Not precompiled]
   - /flags     -> [OK]
   - /map       -> [Not precompiled]
   - *.png      -> [OK]
```

So most of the images in the asset folder are precompiled when calling:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

But the images in the subfolder *comics* and *map* are not precompiled until i add these directory to the precompile-config like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(platform/panel/map/*.png platform/panel/comics/*.png platform/panel/comics/*.jpg)
```

Any idea why these subfolders are not precompiled like the others?